# How can I use NavigationPage in Maui?

Tags: .net, maui

I want to navigate like this in MainPage:

```
private async void btnNav_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Pages.Nav1Page());
}
```

This does not work. Then I get to know that I need to use `NavigationPage` to wrap `MainPage`, like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Page = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

But `NavigationPage` does not implement the `IPage` interface.

Comment: Have you seen this PR [.NET MAUI Gallery PR](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/995)? It implements navigation hierarchy in the sample gallery app

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage();
        MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found in the Weather21 demo app - change your app.xaml.cs like this

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState) =>
        new Window(new NavigationPage(new MainPage())) { Title = "MyApp" };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
```

Answer (score 1):

Page Navigation in .NET MAUI: An Overview
*[Source: Selva Ganapathy Kathiresan, May 27, 2022](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/page-navigation-in-net-maui-an-overview.aspx)*

A typical application needs a hierarchical navigation experience where the user can navigate through pages forward and backward as required.

The .NET MAUI platform provides two primary forms of page navigation to an app:

- Shell.
- Base navigation pages, such as FlyoutPage, TabbedPage, and NavigationPage.

In [this blog](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/page-navigation-in-net-maui-an-overview.aspx), let’s see how we can integrate page navigation in your .NET MAUI application with code examples.