# Opening a new window in MAUI

Tags: maui

In WPF the below code opens a new window.

```
Window abc = new Window();
abc.Show();
```

But for MAUI window,  I cant find the show option. How to open a window in MAUI?

Answer (score 8):

```
var secondWindow = new Window {
    Page = new MySecondPage {
        // ...
    }
};

Application.Current.OpenWindow(secondWindow);
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-preview-11/

Comment: Hi, after upgrading to the latest VS2022 preview (Preview 4) from preview 1.1, I can see OpenWindow option. Then, in MainPage.xaml.cs -> OnCounterClicked method which came by default while creating sample MAUI app, I have coded as this.                 
  private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   count++;
  CounterLabel.Text = $"Current count: {count}";
  SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterLabel.Text);
  Application.Current.OpenWindow(new Window { Page = new MainPage() }); }   
     But its throwing unhandled exception in the last line of code. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can someone suggest on the above unhandled exception at run time when trying to execute the code "Application.Current.OpenWindow(new Window { Page = new MainPage() }); }". Am I missing anything here? In the eventvwr I can see the below exception..                                                                                                                
Faulting application name: MauiSampleAppPreview4_3.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x61954b73
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1466, time stamp: 0xe01c7650

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
```

Comment: Hi, Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());  is not throwing any errors. But its not showing any new Page/Window

Comment: Please put it in button click of a button on MainPage and change new MainPage() to some other page.

Comment: Hi, tried as suggested like this. Coded Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage1()); in the button click event (OnCounterClicked that is already available with sample MAUI project creation) of the MainPage. Its behaving same.. I mean no errors. But not showing the new Page.

Comment: Can you share a github repo? where we can check

Comment: https://github.com/khalidpal/MauiTest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69207022/8438054

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainPage");
```