# Popup Authentication Window In Maui Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I'm using blazor maui to develop a windows application and need to authenticate the user with graph, I can open up the URL in the default browser but would like a popup window instead as is the norm in GUI applications such as Outlook etc when having to login.

The [WebBrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for winforms seems to do what I need but is for winforms and doesn't appear to support .net 6 and maui. Webview2 also seems to do what I need but I can't get it to work in Maui as the [ressources i've found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) are mainly focused on WPF.

Is there anything like this in Maui and how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: What i'm basically interested in is displaying a remote webpage as a popup in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a new contentpage and the showing it in a new window as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866169/opening-a-new-window-in-maui) and in the contentpage having a webview as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-7.0). I achieved what I wanted, just remember to have height request and width request in your webview or it won't show.